# Cancel SingleDate

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker v3.0.3 and initializing all of my inputs that have the `.date` class to where they are single date pickers using the following code:

```js
function checkDateInput() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type','date');

  var notADateValue = 'not-a-date';
  input.setAttribute('value', notADateValue); 

  return (input.value !== notADateValue);
}

// Check if the browser supports the <input type="date" />
if (checkDateInput()) {
  // Change the types on the inputs that are dates
  $('.date').prop('type', 'date');
} else {
  // Iterate through each <input class="date" ... />
  $.each($('.date'), function(key, value) {
    $(value).daterangepicker({
      drops: "up",
      showDropdowns: true,
      singleDatePicker: true,
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Dates</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date_written">Date Written</label>
      <input class="form-control date" id="date_written" name="date_written" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="effective_date">Effective Date</label>
      <input class="form-control date" id="effective_date" name="effective_date" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cancellation_date">Cancellation Date</label>
      <input class="form-control date" id="cancellation_date" name="cancellation_date" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem that I'm running into is if I decide not to select a date and click outside the calendar, it will automatically input today's date when instead I'd prefer that it not insert anything at all. I assume that I need to set the `autoUpdateInput` to False, but I don't know how to manually update the input if a date was actually selected.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue from `chrome` browser, can you explain the steps to fall into the problem?

Comment: @Shidersz - The checkDateInput function would prevent daterangepicker from initializing on Chrome. The idea is that if the web browser has a date input UI, then use it, otherwise if it doesn't then use daterangepicker in its place. So if you launch IE, click on a date field, but click anywhere outside of the daterangepicker UI to simulate a user not selecting a value, it will replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While passing in a callback to the constructor is the easiest way to listen for changes in the selected date range, you can also do something every time the apply button is clicked even if the selection hasn't changed

```js
 
function checkDateInput() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type','date');

  var notADateValue = 'not-a-date';
  input.setAttribute('value', notADateValue); 
return false;
   
  return (input.value !== notADateValue);
}

// Check if the browser supports the <input type="date" />
if (checkDateInput()) {
  // Change the types on the inputs that are dates
  $('.date').prop('type', 'date');
} else {
  // Iterate through each <input class="date" ... />
  $.each($('.date'), function(key, value) {
    $(value).daterangepicker({
      drops: "auto",
      showDropdowns: true,
      singleDatePicker: true,
       autoUpdateInput: false,        
    }).on('hide.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
       //do something, like clearing an input    
     // $(this).val(''); if you want to clear un comment this
   }).on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));                
   });   
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- daterangepicker -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Dates</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date_written">Date Written</label>
      <input class="form-control date" id="date_written" name="date_written" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="effective_date">Effective Date</label>
      <input class="form-control date" id="effective_date" name="effective_date" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cancellation_date">Cancellation Date</label>
      <input class="form-control date" id="cancellation_date" name="cancellation_date" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the requirement, the solution should be changing `autoUpdateInput: false` and handling both`'apply.daterangepicker'` and `'cancel.daterangepicker'`

I report only the piece of code changed below

```
    $.each($('.date'), function(key, value) {

    $(value).daterangepicker({
    drops: "up",
    showDropdowns: true,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    autoUpdateInput: false 
  });

  $(value).on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY')); 
  });

  $(value).on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val('');
    });
```

Also, I think you should [change the order of inclusion of **js**](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/320) this way:

```
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
<!-- FR: https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/320 switched js loading order -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: The proposed solution is similar  to [what is shown in the example5 taken from the official documentation](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example5) if this answer does not fully meet your expectations I hope at least it can be inspirational, or let me message and I'll try to better understand what the need is